# How do we calculate solvent accessible surface area (SASA) for a system simulated with annealing protocols in Gromacs?

Tags: simulation, molecular-dynamics

I calculated SASA for 4 systems using the following command. The trajectory file (run.xtc) is not treated with gmx trjconv option. In my MD simulation, I followed two annealing cycles in each 50 ns simulation time. In the graph, I observed a pattern at every 25 ns and I am unable to explain why I get it. I would like to know whether I did any incorrect step in calculating SASA or whether this SASA behavior is normal in annealing. Appreciate your help on this.

gmx sasa -s run.tpr -f .run.xtc -o sasa_run.xvg -n index.ndx -tu ns

[image]